# Asymptotic normality of the MLE of a collection of Poisson random variables

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood

The MLE for a collection of $n$ Poisson random variables can be determined with the standard method; set the derivative of the log-likelihood to $0$, and what pops out is that
$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i.$$
My question is about the asymptotic normality of this MLE, with asymptotic normality defined by:
$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0) \to^d N\left(0, \frac{1}{I(\theta_0)}\right),$$
where $\theta_0$ is the true parameter and $I$ is the Fisher information.

Now, to determine the asymptotic normality, we first evaluate the Fisher information. In this case,
$$I(\lambda) = \frac{n}{\lambda},$$
so
$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\lambda} - \lambda) \to^d N\left(0, \frac{\lambda}{n}\right).$$

I would assume that this means that
$$(\hat{\lambda} - \lambda) \to^d N\left(0, \frac{\lambda}{n^2}\right),$$
and thus
$$\hat{\lambda} \to^d N\left(\lambda, \frac{\lambda}{n^2}\right).$$

However, it turns out that this is wrong: it should be
$$\hat{\lambda} \to^d N\left(\lambda, \frac{\lambda}{n}\right),$$
but I can't figure out why. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What does $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\lambda} - \lambda) \to_d N(0, \lambda/n)$ mean? How does the limiting distribution depend on $n$ after taking the $n \to \infty$ limit?

Comment: As I understand it, it means that the rescaled difference between the estimated $\hat{\lambda}$ and the true $\lambda$ will follow a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\lambda/n$. I guess in the limit what'll happen is that $\hat{\lambda}$ will be equal to $\lambda$, since we'll have a normal distribution with mean $0$ and $0$ variance?

Comment: Are you saying $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\lambda} - \lambda)$ is normal with mean, variance $0, \lambda/n$? That is false.

Comment: That's what I thought convergence in distribution meant. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Convergence in distribution roughly means the cdfs of $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots $ converges to the cdf  of some random variable $Y$. So of course the limiting cdf cannot depend on $n$ once you take the limit.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thanks! But how does that explain the $1/n$ factor that's wrong in the variance?

Comment: It doesn't explain anything. I am just pointing out that your very first step is wrong. Imagine the sequence $1/n$; it converges to $0$. Does $0$ depend on $n$? Of course not. Similarly, the limit of convergence of distribution cannot depend on $n$ in anyway. $n$ should not appear on the right-hand side of a $\to_d$ symbol period.

Comment: Alright, so $I(\lambda)$ should just be $\lambda$, and then after dividing by $\sqrt{n}$ we divide the variance of the normal distribution by $n$, and we get $\frac{\lambda}{n}$. Is that correct?

Comment: The Fisher information $I(\cdot)$ in the asymptotic normality of MLE is based on a single observation, so it is just $I(\lambda)=1/\lambda$. Why are you dividing by $\sqrt n$?